# Change Load Plan execution time but nothing happens is Oracle ODI

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I want to change the execution time of a load plan in Oracle ODI Scheduling. I change Starting date and times manually but it is again executed in previous date and time settings. How can i be able to execute the load plans in required date and time? Thanks

---

EDITING VERSION 1:
The Images are 
[image: scheduling]
[image: agents]

### [image: versions]

P.S.: We have also converted to "Active for the period" and didn't work. Is it related with the Java version?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the schedules of a Load Plan or a Scenario will update the schedule information in the repository but will not update that information in the agent.

There is therefore an extra step to perform. On the topology tab, a right click on the physical agent will give the option `Update Schedule`. That will refresh the agent memory with the schedule stored into the repository.

Comment: I have tried to `Update Schedule`, bu does not affect the `Agent`.

Comment: Then we need more information to help : ODI release, type of agent, scheduling parameters (maybe with a screenshot), operator screenshots, ...